# Rotating a set of points around two fixed points

Tags: graphics

I have a set of points that are used to draw a shape. I want to rotate this shape without moving its start and end points. I tried to illustrate what I want in the image below (original shape on left, interpolated on right). Are there any algorithms to do that? I researched Hermite Spline and Bezier Curves but I did not think they are applicable in my problem.

[image]

My goal is achieving this action with only 2D transformations:

[image: animation]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a rotation that fixes two points. 2D rotations, by definition, only fix one point, the centre of the rotation. Any 2D transformation that fixes more than two points cannot be a rotation. So what transformation are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry for bad English. I mean a rotation like rotating an arm of a human. The shoulder and armpit is still, but the arm is rotating.

Comment: You mean that the rotation is in the third dimension? Or you are skewing them by moving control points? Or the starting and ending point is fixed, you perform rotation from S-E midpoint and connect the result? The distances between segments change, right? If you could describe your goal a bit more that would be nice, the picture looks a bit like dragging springs.

Comment: I suggest: Calculate the center between the two fixed points. Then rotate every point  except for those fixed around the calculated center.

Comment: @AndreasT how couldn't I think that ? Thank you so much ! It worked well.

Comment: There is one more thing: do you accept the "hand" changing length? Or you would like to keep it the same, to rotate around elbow and keep arm size fixed?

Comment: @EvilJS the length may change a little bit, it is not a big problem for me.